# javascript object oriented call function inside function or call function insede var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop

i try to understand javascript now
what i really want to achieve is something like this :

```
var data = Data.GetData();//with or without parameter Data.GetData(x)
//or
var data = Data.Row.GetData();
```

what i understand from other oop languange i just create class like this :

```
Class Data{
  public static String GetData()
  {
     return "data";
  }
}
```

So I can call :

```
String data = Data.GetData();
//or
Data _data = new Data();
String x = _data.GetData();
```

but how in javascript?
i think like this :

```
function Data(){
  function GetData(){
    retun "data";
  }
}
```

but it didn't work. :(
please help me understand oop how to make this in javascript, with example code :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In javascript you can declare a function as a constructor (by making sure it doesn't return anything) and then have methods for that class applied to all its instances by using prototypal inheritance.

```
function Data () {
}
Data.prototype.GetData = function () {
  return 'data';
}
```

you can then use it like so:

```
var data = new Data();
var str = data.GetData();
```

if you want a static method you can omit the prototype keyword

```
Data.GetData = function () { return 'data'; }
```

If instead your Data object is a single object and you don't want to reuse any of its methods and members you can simply declare it like this:

```
var Data = {
  GetData: function () { return 'data'; }
};
```

and then do

```
Data.GetData();
```

Answer (score 2):

`Data` is a simple `Object`, and `GetData` is a key with function as value

```
var Data = {
    GetData: function() {
           return "data";
     }
}
```

in the second case:

```
var Data = {
    Row: {
         GetData: function() {
               return "data";
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions in JavaScript are first class objects. "Methods" are just properties on objects that point to functions. The act of calling the function *via* a property reference is a bit special, in that it sets the meaning of `this` within the call to the function (`this` is set to the object the property was on). Unlike some other languages you may be used to, that is a *runtime* thing decided by how the function is called, not a compile-time thing decided by where the function is declared/defined.

To be able to do this:

```
var data = Data.GetData();
```

...you need to have an object, `Data`, that has a property called `GetData` that refers to a function. You can build that like this:

```
var Data = {
    GetData: function() {
        // ...your code here...
    }
};
```

...or any of several other ways, such as:

```
var Data = {};
Data.GetData = function() {
    // ...your code here...
};
```

...or

```
var Data = {};
Data.GetData = GetData;
function GetData() {
    // ...your code here...
}
```

More on my blog: [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
function Data() {

    this.getData = function() {
        return "data";
    };

    this.ROW = {
        getData : function() {
            return "Row Data";
        }
    }
}
```

You the call the function from a new instance of Data:

```
new Data().getData();
```

OR

```
new Data().ROW.getData();
```

This will return the data.